# OpenCV shows LAB TIF picture in weird colors

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, color-space, lab-color-space

I am trying to show an image using OpenCV with Python, but it appears with different colors.

The original image (LAB color space, TIF file extension) looks like this:

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('Photos/example.tif') # read the image
```

When I output it using `cv.imshow('Title', img)`
The picture looks like this:

[image]

So I tried this line of code:

```
LAB_img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
cv.imshow('Title', LAB_img) # show the LAB version
```

and the output looks like this:

[image]

I also tried RGB2LAB or LAB2BGR, and the result outputs are all weird.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with  cv2 and some tif files exported with some settings that cv2 did not like..  If your file has a transparency channel, you could try reading the image like this and see if that fixes anything:

`img = cv2.imread('Photos/example.tif',  cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)`

If that doesn't solve the issue, and no one else responds, I'd recommend you try reading the files using [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) or [OpenImageIO](https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio)

Comment: @Ishay Frenkel the LAB related output is not at all related to the problem you have. LAB is a different colour space. So it provides a different perspective to color. If you try converting any image containing similar or same colors to LAB, you will get similar color transformation. Please have a look at this article https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space